# Django: caching images

Tags: django, image, caching, redis

I am currently using [django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) which provides great benefits by caching compressed CSS and JS files.

Now I would like to cache images. I know that browser caching can be enabled using HTTP headers (downstream caching) but I would like to use Redis here (it is already used by django-compressor).

So this is my first question: is it right to cache images with Redis?

I have read interesting things about [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail) and its caching through the thumbnail template tag. I thought maybe I could use it in a raw way but the tag requires a geometry argument.

Is there an existing Django package I could use to cache images? Should I write a template tag similar to sorl-thumbnail's thumbnail tag to enable image caching by using [Django's built-in cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#accessing-the-cache)?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "is it right"? What kind of caching do you want to do - you mean reading images from memory instead of from disk?

Comment: Yes, II would like to read images from memory. There are many resources about downstream caching but I did not find anything interesting about in-memory cache with Redis...

Comment: "So this is my first question: is it right to cache images with Redis?" no

Comment: Caching is generally for the output of expensive (processor) operations. Reading an image from disk is not expensive. Why would you want to cache it in memory?

Comment: Well, because I lack some knowledge about caching and needed your advice :)

Comment: +1 on Varnish for many useful cases. Redis can be proper in some situations, just don't see the need in your case - the OS does disk caching on its own, and unless you KNOW exactly why you need the caching, you probably don't.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for redis and isn't a good use case for django.  If you want to cache images in memory to serve from the server, front your django app server (like uwsgi or gunicorn) and nginx and use varnish to cache the images in memory.  Redis does not do great for storing/retrieving large blobs.

Comment: This is interesting! Do you have any resource about your last statement?

Comment: http://martin.podval.eu/2015/02/performance-redis-nosql-blob.html — note the dramatic drop in TPS (transactions per second) as the size of the blob increases.